How do I revert to the old microcode?
Ubuntu 20.04 is installed. A new microcode was uploaded with the update. How can I learn the old microcode? And how can I revert to the old microcode? A container that was working before doesn't work anymore after restarting Ubuntu, so I think microcode has changed. A microcode change can affect this container.

What leads you to the conclusion that "A new microcode was uploaded with the update?"

This SuperUser question may help answer your question. If the microcode is only part of the OS, selecting the previous kernel at boot time may provide what you seek.

What error message do you get? Any reason to suspect microcode?
